# Работа с русскоязычным XML в PHP

Tags: php, xml, 1с, simplexml

Подскажите каким образом работать с русскоязычным XML файлом в PHP, таким например как отдаёт 1С.

К примеру:

```xml
<Цены>
    <Цена>
        <Представление>134 RUB за шт</Представление>
        <ИдТипаЦены>bc76faa9-6a31-11e8-94cd-60a44c3fcca4</ИдТипаЦены>
        <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>134</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
        <Валюта>RUB</Валюта>
        <Налог>
            <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
            <УчтеноВСумме>true</УчтеноВСумме>
        </Налог>
    </Цена>
</Цены>
```

Кроме как построчно читать и обрабатывать функциями работы со строками?

SimpleXml сразу выбрасывает миллион ошибок об отсутствие открывающихся и закрывающихся тегов. Где я ошибся?

Кто сталкивался? Как быть?

Comment: а кодировка файла какая? после 1с 1251 небось, в utf8 переведите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В кодировке utf-8 все прекрасно работает

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<Цены>
    <Цена>
        <Представление>134 RUB за шт</Представление>
        <ИдТипаЦены>bc76faa9-6a31-11e8-94cd-60a44c3fcca4</ИдТипаЦены>
        <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>134</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
        <Валюта>RUB</Валюта>
        <Налог>
            <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
            <УчтеноВСумме>true</УчтеноВСумме>
        </Налог>
    </Цена>
</Цены>');

var_dump( $xml->{'Цена'}->{'ЦенаЗаЕдиницу'});

object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "134"
}
```

Comment: Да действительно кодировка.